# Where does Apache get the 'last modifed' date for its automatic indexes?

Tags: apache, operating-system

I have a Solaris server running Apache, and I am using the following .htaccess to generate automatic indexes.

```
Options +Indexes
# SET INDEX OPTIONS
IndexOptions +NameWidth=*
```

Where does the "Last modified" date come from in the index that is generated?

[image: index screenshot]

It does not appear to be from any of the filesystem dates.

[image: filesystem screenshot]

Note that I copy these directories to this location. It seems to be showing the creation date for the directory that I copied, not the date that I copied it. If it's not the atime, ctime, mtime, or crtime, where does Apache find this date?

Comment: Does it correctly report the last modified date of ordinary files (as opposed to directories)? What is the last modified date of the files contained in these directories?

Comment: Yes, files within these directories show the date correctly. For that matter, so do directories within these directories show the date correctly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the fact that these wrong-date directories were copied, but I can't understand where else the date might be coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation states](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html):

> [Last-modified] is only valid if the operating system and file system return appropriate stat() results.

Since it is not working for your system, you can turn off the last-modified with: `IndexOptions SuppressLastModified`

Answer (score 3):

I found reason of this issue: mod_autoindex uses mtime of index.html inside folder, not folder mtime.
Reproduced on CentOS 6 with latest updates.

Comment: Same here with ubuntu 16.04 latest updates as of now. Many thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Apache is listing the modified date of the newest file inside the folder (not the folder itself).